# What can I do to restore disk performance on slower Ubuntu VM

Tags: performance, vmware, disk

I have Ubuntu 12.04 (x86) running under VMware Workstation 10.0.5 on a Windows 7 x64 host. Disk access in this VM is noticeably slow - it takes ages just to start Firefox, for example, and the disk light is on the whole time. `hdparm -tT` confirms this:

```
/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   18100 MB in  1.99 seconds = 9073.75 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:  42 MB in  3.54 seconds =  11.85 MB/sec
```

However, I have 2 other VMs on the same host partition (Ubuntu 11.04 and 14.04) and they're both OK:

```
/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   17388 MB in  2.00 seconds = 8703.76 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 210 MB in  3.07 seconds =  68.37 MB/sec

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   17012 MB in  2.00 seconds = 8511.87 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 282 MB in  3.01 seconds =  93.63 MB/sec
```

The big difference is that the slow machine has been used a lot over time and had a lot of stuff installed, so the virtual disk is 32GB (vs 4GB and 6GB for the other VMs). What can I do to restore disk performance? I tried the VMware De-fragment and Compact commands that they didn't help. The file system is ext4 in all 3 cases.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating a new virtual disk in VMware and manually copying the data across. It worked - the machine is now noticeably faster and hdparm reports:

```
/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   18598 MB in  1.99 seconds = 9322.95 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 394 MB in  3.00 seconds = 131.31 MB/sec
```

The steps were:

1. Shut down the machine.
2. Add a new virtual disk device (sdb).
3. Boot from an Ubuntu LiveCD.
4. Partition the new disk (I had only 1 partition).
5. mount both old and new partitions
6. copy data using `cp -ax /mnt/sda1 /mnt/sdb1`
7. Shut down
8. Remove the old disk and change the new one to node SCSI 0:0, so it becomes "sda".
9. Boot from the Ubuntu LiveCD again and fix grub using the ["via chroot" method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot)
10. Edit `/etc/fstab`, which referred to the old partition by UUIDs to use `/dev/sda1` (or I could have used the new UUID)
11. Reboot from the new disk and enjoy a faster VM!